# ¿Como puedo obtener la posición de un Spinner para después sumarlo?

Tags: android, spinner

El asunto esta así, tengo 9 Spinners, y cada Spinner tienen los mismos Items (Nada, Poco, mucho, bastante). Deseo realizar la suma de las posiciones para dar un resultado.

Comment: Has hecho algún avance ? intentaste algo ? coloca el código aca para saber que has hecho...

Answer (score 1):

La forma de obtener la posición del spinner es:

```
spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

ten en cuenta que inicia en 0....n

Referencia de la documentación: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItemPosition ()